# Range doesn't change multiple cells

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub ButtonLower()

Range("b2", "b7").Value = Range("b2", "b7").Value - 2

End Sub
Sub ButtonHigher()

Range("b2", "b7").Value = Range("b2", "b7").Value + 2

End Sub
```

The end result is that only `B2`'s value changes, not the entire range. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do a mathematical operation against an array as a whole directly.  Use Evaluate:

```
With ActiveSheet.Range("B2:B7")
    .Value = ActiveSheet.Evaluate(.Address & " - 2")
End With
```

And

```
With ActiveSheet.Range("B2:B7")
    .Value = ActiveSheet.Evaluate(.Address & " + 2")
End With
```

Or you can load the whole into a variant array and loop the array:

```
Sub ButtonLower()
    Dim arr() As Variant
    arr = ActiveSheet.Range("b2:b7").Value

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
        Dim j As Long
        For j = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
            arr(i, j) = arr(i, j) - 2
        Next j
    Next i

    ActiveSheet.Range("b2:b7").Value = arr
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice! I was looking for my evaluate examples

Comment: For small ranges it is quick and easy.  Larger ranges I would either do your copy paste or the variant array loop. @Davesexcel

Answer (score 2):

If you have the value to add or subtract in A1 then you can copy A1 and add it to the Range cells.

Or you can use a loop.

```
Sub AddVal()
    Range("A1").Copy
    Range("B2:B7").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlAdd, SkipBlanks:= _
                                False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
Sub SubVal()
    Range("A1").Copy
    Range("B2:B7").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlSubtract, SkipBlanks:= _
                                False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub

Sub LoopIt()
    For Each cell In Range("B2:B7")
        cell.Value = cell.Value + 2
    Next
End Sub
```